# android - cannot request in JsonArrayRequest

Tags: php, android, kotlin

I am a student studying Volley request.
There's an error that I can't solve, so I'm asking you to find a solution.

I don't understand why can't POST from Android to PHP at all.
**It worked well in other situations, but not only in JsonArrayRequest.**

I'll attach the code, so if there's any problem with my code, please let me know.

This is string request code in Android Studio

```
package kr.ac.castcommunity.cc.request

import android.util.Log
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.Response.success
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import java.util.HashMap
import org.json.JSONObject
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import org.json.JSONArray


class CommentRequest(boardid : String , listener: Response.Listener<JSONArray>) :
    JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, JSONArray(), listener, Response.ErrorListener { error ->
        Log.d("COMMENT ERROR", "Server Response FAIL: $error")
    }) {
    private val parameters: MutableMap<String, String>
    companion object {
        private val URL = "http://MyIP/cc/commentlist.php"
    }

    init {
        parameters = HashMap()
        parameters["boardid"] = boardid
        Log.d("boardID :",boardid)
    }

    override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {

        return parameters
    }

}
```

This is PHP code
(It works well if I randomly assign a variable.)
(But it doesn't work when I interlock it.)

```
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "cc");
  mysqli_query($con, 'SET NAMES utf8');

  $boardid = $_POST["boardid"]; // but It's not operating
  //$boardid = "1"; // It's operating
  $boardid = (int)$boardid;
   
  $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "select * from comment where boardid = ?");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "i", $boardid);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

  mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $commentid, $boardid, $content, $writer, $date);
 
  $response = array();
  $response["success"] = false;
  $result = array();

  while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["commentid"] = $commentid;
    $response["boardid"] = $boardid;
    $response["content"] = $content;
    $response["writer"] = $writer;
    $response["date"] = substr($date,10,-3);
    array_push($result, array(
   "success"=>$response["success"], 
   "commentid" => $response["commentid"],
   "boardid" => $response["boardid"], 
   "content" => $response["content"],
   "writer" => $response["writer"], 
   "date" => $response["date"]));
  }

  echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

```
D/COMMENT ERROR: Server Response Fail: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

and response code

```
       val boardid = intent.getIntExtra("bnum", 0)
       mCommentRecyclerView = comment_recyclerView

        val responseListener = Response.Listener<JSONArray> { response ->
            try {
                Log.d("response", "comment response Start")
                for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
                    val jobject = response.getJSONObject(i)
                    val success = jobject.getBoolean("success")
                    val boardid = jobject.getInt("boardid")
                    val commentid = jobject.getInt("commentid")
                    val content = jobject.getString("content")
                    val date = jobject.getString("date")
                    val writer = jobject.getString("writer")

                    if (success == true) {
                        mDatas.add(Comment(boardid, commentid, content, date, writer))
                    } else {
                        return@Listener
                    }
                }
                mAdpater = CommentAdapter(this, mDatas)
                mCommentRecyclerView!!.adapter = mAdpater
                mCommentRecyclerView!!.addItemDecoration(BoardDecoration(20))
                val lm = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                lm.reverseLayout = true
                lm.stackFromEnd = true
                mCommentRecyclerView!!.layoutManager = lm
                mCommentRecyclerView!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
                val decoration = DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
                mCommentRecyclerView!!.addItemDecoration(decoration)
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        val commentRequest = CommentRequest(boardid.toString(), responseListener)
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@DetailActivity)
        queue.add(commentRequest)
```

I really don't know why. I need your help.

Comment: Please update the code of how to call CommentRequest.

Comment: New update succeeded. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Through your error message. I think there is a problem with the conversion of String to JsonObject.

You can print out the response from the server first, and then print out the conversion parameters.

I think the error appears in the for loop code below. Please check if the error is caused by the `<br>` tag.

```kotlin
Log.d("response", "comment response Start")
  for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
    val jobject = response.getJSONObject(i)
    val success = jobject.getBoolean("success")
    val boardid = jobject.getInt("boardid")
    val commentid = jobject.getInt("commentid")
    val content = jobject.getString("content")
    val date = jobject.getString("date")
    val writer = jobject.getString("writer")

    println(jobject)
    println(success)
    println(boardid)
    println(commentid)
    println(content)
    println(date)
    println(writer)

    if (success == true) {
       mDatas.add(Comment(boardid, commentid, content, date, writer))
    } else {
       return@Listener
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't understand.
If you look at the PHP code, **the code worked normally when the "boardid" variable was specified separately.** However, an error occurred while POSTing the "boardid" variable from Android to PHP.

Comment: That means there is a problem with this `boardid` in Post.

Comment: Yeah, but it worked when the exact same code was "StringRequest". But it didn't work the "JSONARrayRequest" way. But I'm not sure what the difference is.